# How to select the title with the latest datetime?

Tags: php, mysql

I have these two tables in mysql:

```
posts (id)
post_titles (id, post_id, title, datetime, user_id)
post_contents (id, post_id, content, datetime, user_id)
post_statuses (id, post_id, status, datetime, user_id)

posts (id) == posts_titles (post_id)
```

In the `post_titles` and `post_contents` can be multiple entries for 1 `posts (id)`.

What i need, is to select the title which has the latest datetime. I would have to select it all by using the `posts (id)`. How  could i do that?

EDIT: i need to select the latest title and latest content together or latest title, latest content and latest status.

Comment: use `max(datetime)` and `group by post_id` to get max datetime for that post... join that back to the `title` with `post_id` and that max datetime

Comment: someone asked, then deleted a comment "wouldn't that be slow?" my response: dunno.  that would probably depend on a whole bunch of info not given here...

Answer (score 4):

Order by the column you are interested in (datetime in this case) and do a limit of 1. This will order the rows by datetime in descending order (newest will be first). And then limit 1 to just get the first row.

```
SELECT * FROM post_titles ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Use a join to add get the post_contents

Comment: Worst case, do a sub select: **select everything from all tables where id in (select id FROM post_titles ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT t.title, c.content
FROM post_titles t 
JOIN post_contents c ON t.post_id = c.post_id
WHERE 
t.datetime = 
    (SELECT MAX(x.datetime) FROM post_titles x WHERE t.post_id = x.post_id)
AND 
c.datetime = 
    (SELECT MAX(y.datetime) FROM post_contents y WHERE c.post_id = y.post_id);
```

I'm assuming that all the datetime are equal, because when you add something on the tables, the content are created at the same time.

**EDIT:** Now it doesn't matter if the datetime are equal. Check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

To build on the answer from Mark S (I can't figure out how to quote or link to his answer...)

Since there are `datetime` fields on both `post_title` and `post_contents` tables, you'll have to specify which table's column to reference as you do the ordering, like this:

```sql
SELECT `title`, `content`
FROM `post_titles` t
    JOIN `post_contents` c USING (`post_id`)
ORDER BY t.datetime DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Yes, because of the `LIMIT 1` at the end of the query this will only give the post whose title has been updated most recently. This is what I thought you were after with "the title which has the latest datetime." If you want something more than that, or multiple post contents based on the latest time of one of the titles, then the "sub select" approach in Mark S.'s comment is the best approach.